# Transparent picturebox over another picturebox

Tags: c#, .net, transparency

How can I put a transparent PictureBox on another PictureBox?

One transparent PictureBox works on my form but i can not put a transparent PictureBox over another PictureBox.

[Here](http://www.4shared.com/photo/hU_NrUcF/New_Bitmap_Image.html) is a picture from my problem.

Comment: See this question for solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234999/transparency-problem-by-overlapped-pictureboxs-at-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`Control.BringToFront`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx) on the `PictureBox` you want to be in front (on top).

Comment: thanks for your attention.
i do that. but it does not work yet.

Comment: Yes Of course.
http://www.4shared.com/photo/RD90H8fd/5_-_Copy.html
----------------
even i called method on form_load

Comment: I mean the code, I can see that you bring it to the front.  What happens when you run it? Does the picturebox not show? Whats you expected result?

Comment: would you please give me an example? :(
still second picturebox is not transparent.

Comment: Are you sure the image is transparent? Can you post that as well.

Comment: I putted picture boxes on panel. 
i cant put on picturebox.
thank you