# Picture box On Picture Box

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, transparency, picturebox

This is in regards to C# coding, im quite new to this programming language, and do not know much about any other as well, but what i would like to achieve is to have a picture box as the background, and have another picture box over lapping it but the transparent part has to show the picture box behind. I have been able to have a transparent picture box, but the thing is it only shows the form's back color rather than the picture box behind it. can anyone help with this?

IN other words a picture box over a picture box, but able to see through the first picture box where it is clear, and see the picture box behind.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of using two picture-box's, you could create a custom control and override the draw method so that you can draw the two images yourself with more options and less complications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms semi-transparent PNG over semi-transparent PNG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455484/winforms-semi-transparent-png-over-semi-transparent-png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Project -> Add user control. 
Give that User Control the BackGroundImage.
Drag your picturebox onto the the usercontrol. Make the PictureBox's Backcolor transparent.
Build the project.

In the designer, you should be able to drag your new usercontrol onto the form. 
This will do what you want.

Comment: okay, i don't know if i'm interpreting your solution correctly, but what you want me to do is, set the image of the picture box that's on top as the background, and set the image of the picture box that's on the bottom as image? 
Because that is not working for me.

Comment: Hmm the transparent part only seems to be showing the form's background, rather than the background of the other picturebox.

Comment: what do you mean by "adding" it?

Comment: can you give me an example? lets say picturebox1 is on top and picturebox2 is under :$ sorry for troubling you so much >.<

Comment: how do i drag the new user control? :$

Comment: Tools > Options > Windows Forms Designer > General : AutoToolboxPopulate --> True.
The UserControl you created should appear in your toolbox, when looking at the form in designer view. Make sure you have built your solution--> 'F6'

Answer (score 0):

for background, you can use Graphics. build a paint event for your form visually:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("address of image"), 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
}
```

it will color the form and you don't need picturebox for background.

Comment: Yes, i am aware of this, but this is not what i was trying to achieve, as i want two interacting picture boxs, and i already have a background for the form.