# Colouring in a picture using overlays or filled polygons

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a VB.net form application to visually fill in a floor plan with different colours according to reservation status.

The basic floor plan is white and the idea is to colour in the various apartments in different colours depending on some variables.

I have tried overlaying .png pictures on top of each other but this doesn't work due to the non-true nature of transparency in visual studio as soon as you overlay more than 2 PNGs.

Not much more success with drawing polygons either

Here is what I would like to achieve and I'd be grateful for some help or suggestions:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms semi-transparent PNG over semi-transparent PNG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455484/winforms-semi-transparent-png-over-semi-transparent-png)

Answer (score 3):

Try drawing on top of the image with a brush that has an alpha value:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(backImage, New Point(0, 0))

  Dim room As New List(Of Point)
  room.Add(New Point(45, 48))
  room.Add(New Point(165, 48))
  room.Add(New Point(190, 75))
  room.Add(New Point(190, 234))
  room.Add(New Point(150, 234))
  room.Add(New Point(150, 245))
  room.Add(New Point(45, 245))

  Using br As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Blue))
    e.Graphics.FillPolygon(br, room.ToArray())
  End Using
  Using p As New Pen(Color.Blue, 3)
    e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(p, room.ToArray())
  End Using

  MyBase.OnPaint(e)
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response. I'll give that a go. The other issue with drawing is that is provides a fixed position so if the base image is extended in fillscreen mode, the polygon doesn't follow.
Would you know a way to make sure everything resizes nicely?

Thanks again for the quick response!

Comment: @user1433452 That would be a new question.  You can use `e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(x, y);` to move the polygon to a new position.  For resizing or more complicated scaling, have a look at the Matrix class.

Comment: When trying your solution with a picturebox, is there a way to draw the polygon on top of the picturebox as it seems to end up behind it and not show. Thanks.

Comment: @user1433452 You have to use the PictureBox's Paint event.  `Invalidate()` it whenever you need it re-drawn.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this but perhaps I should clarify my initial question: What I would like to do is have say 2 buttons and when one is clicked, certain rooms turn blue and when the other is clicked the blue rooms disappear and other red ones appear. I hope it's ok to ask and thank you for your much appreciated help so far.

Comment: @user1433452 Sounds like you need a class that holds the roomID and polygon points, color, reservation, etc.  The drawing routine then is just a matter of drawing the rooms you requested.  If you need help with that, try posting another question and reference this question for background information.  Post the code you are trying to use to accomplish that.  Stack Overflow is good at helping you fix your code, but it doesn't react too well if you just ask for the code.

Comment: I have managed to do this with the following code but now need the graphic to stay in place and stretch when the form is resized and stretches the base picture         

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim pts As New List(Of Point)
        pts.Add(New Point(5, 3))
        pts.Add(New Point(150, 13))
        pts.Add(New Point(120, 45))
        pts.Add(New Point(15, 15))

        Dim br As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Blue))
        PictureBox2.CreateGraphics.FillPolygon(br, pts.ToArray())
    End Sub

Comment: @user1433452 Like I commented earlier, see the [Matrix Class](http://www.bobpowell.net/zoompicbox.htm)  Don't hesitate to post a **new question** if you get stuck.

Comment: @user1433452 if this answered your question please mark it checked