# How to make a pictureBox transparent?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, controls, transparent

Hello Im trying to do in my project 2 layers of pictureBox controls.

1 is for a moving object and the other 1 to draw a line.

However the upper PB is hidding the lower PB even if I set the BackColor to transparent..

is there any other way or a special control to overcome this problem?

I searched for some answers in google but didnt found what I need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms semi-transparent PNG over semi-transparent PNG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455484/winforms-semi-transparent-png-over-semi-transparent-png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set opacity of the pictureBox by using [THIS CODE](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/198575/C-Opacity-Of-Picturebox).