# Is it possible to create a non-shaped control?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, background, transparent

I'm trying to place an image that has no definitive shape (a hat for example) on top of a different image control.
The thing is, since the control has a definitive shape, it leaves the default background color to cover up the space left blank. The image control is the exact same size of the image.
I tried using control.BackColor = Color.Transparent; but it doesn't seem to work.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is the image itself transparent? For example, PNG images support the transparent color. This is pretty crucial for your attempt to work...

Comment: Edited your title. Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: I believe this is WinForms, so you may want to specify this in your tags (instead of background or picturebox perhaps). I originally was going to answer this for WPF before noticing `BackColor`.

Comment: Yes my image has a transparent background as a PNG format.

Comment: can u provide some code to clarify exactly whats needed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms semi-transparent PNG over semi-transparent PNG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455484/winforms-semi-transparent-png-over-semi-transparent-png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Control.Region` for this purpose

```
GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
path.AddEllipse(control.ClientRectangle);
control.Region = new Region(path);
```

try this, you can create any shape using `GraphicsPath` and set it to `Region` for instance I created ellipse.

**Edit**

If you just want to set BackColor = Color.Transparent. for some reason some controls doesn't allow this. in such cases you can do the following

```
public class CustomControl1 : Control
{
    public CustomControl1()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
    }
}
```

Create a descendant of your control and set `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);` that should do the trick

Comment: What about unconventional shapes? Like this one: http://img2-2.timeinc.net/people/i/2013/pets/news/130218/cat-monopoly-600.jpg

Comment: If that image has Transparent Background you can set your Control's `BackGroundImage` Property and Set Control.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

Comment: @SharonJDDorot - You might find this article useful:  http://bobpowell.net/region_from_bitmap.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your `Image Control` (like a `PictureBox`) is not moved (by holding mouse down and dragging) by user at runtime, you can use this technique which allows you to display images on top of each other. The images should have transparent background:

```
public class ImageControl : Control {
   public ImageControl(){
      SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
   }
   public Image Image {get;set;}
   protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
      get {
          CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
          cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
          return cp;
      }
   }
   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e){
      if(Image != null) e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, Point.Empty);
   }
}
```

You can use the control above instead of a `PictureBox`. Moving this control by dragging at runtime causes flicker much. So if you want so I think there is only 1 solution which uses `Region`. In this approach, you have to turn your `Bitmap` to a `Region` and assign this `Region` for your `Control.Region` property. The link given by `Chris Dunaway` is very helpful for you to do this. However I have to say that the `Region` has not a smooth border as you may expect. That's a shortage of this approach. For your convenience, I'll post the code with a little modification here, this code uses `LockBits` which will outperform the original code:

```
public class Util {
//invert will toggle backColor to foreColor (in fact, I mean foreColor here is the Solid Color which makes your image distinct from the background).
    public static Region RegionFromBitmap(Bitmap bm, Color backColor, bool invert)
    {
        Region rgn = new Region();
        rgn.MakeEmpty();//This is very important            
        int argbBack = backColor.ToArgb();
        BitmapData data = bm.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        int[] bits = new int[bm.Width * bm.Height];
        Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, bits, 0, bits.Length);
        //
        Rectangle line = Rectangle.Empty;
        line.Height = 1;
        bool inImage = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < bm.Height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bm.Width; j++)
            {
                int c = bits[j + i * bm.Width];
                if (!inImage)
                {
                    if (invert ? c == argbBack : c != argbBack)
                    {
                        inImage = true;
                        line.X = j;
                        line.Y = i;
                    }
                }
                else if(invert ? c != argbBack : c == argbBack)
                {
                    inImage = false;
                    line.Width = j - line.X;
                    rgn.Union(line);
                }
            }
        }
        bm.UnlockBits(data);
        return rgn;
    }
}
//Use the code
//if your Bitmap is a PNG with transparent background, you can get the Region from it like this:
Region rgn = Util.RegionFromBitmap(yourPng, Color.FromArgb(0), false);
//if your Bitmap has a figure with solid color of Black, you can get the Region like this:
Region rgn = Util.RegionFromBitmap(yourPng, Color.Black, true);
```