# Getting a png file (transparent) into a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, png, panel, transparent

Hey I'm a beginning programmer and I have to do a big school project. The problem I'm having is I have a picture of a roadsign, now the file itself is a png and it is transparent (I checked in photoshop). Now when I put this image in my panel it has a white background. While it's transparent in photoshop. I don't want the white background because I think it's ugly and also a little bit sloppy.
The image is loaded in the right window where you can see all your properties.
I tried:

```
panel.Backcolor = Color.Transparent ; // 1

panel.Backcolor = Color.getFromArgb(0,0,0,0); // 2
```

**EDIT1:**
I work with [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms).

**EDIT2:**

```
this.startPanel1.BackgroundImage = global::DragnDrop.Properties.Resources.BeladenToestanf;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file was exported from Photoshop with transparency turned on?

Comment: Yes , I'm 100% sure, when I look at the picture with a photoviewer I can Clearly see that the picture is transparent, but when I load it in VB in my panel it's not transparent anymore. Also I work a lot with photoshop and in photoshop I'm not a noob ;)

Comment: Can you post the code where you are loading the image and inserting it into the panel?

Comment: WinForms controls don't really support transparency

Comment: I am using a drag and drop on my picture, but I just need to know if I can make my image transparent ;) It's just a design issue that's all ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I used WinForms, but you might be able to get away with loading your picture into a PictureBox control.

[Winforms semi-transparent PNG over semi-transparent PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10455484/436282)

Comment: This is the answer to my problem , Thanks ;) unfortunatly I may not use a picturebox, I need to use a panel from my professor. But then I'll need to live with this problem. It's only a design issue ;)